# limiting emails from smtpappender (log4Net)

Tags: log4net

I am looking for a way to limit SmtpAppender to limit number of emails sent in case of same error is occurred multiple times in a defined time span.

I don't know if it is even possible, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not tried this extended SMTP appender, but it seems to be be what you need.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200804.mbox/%3C6D3CA9B0BEA31640B4E6338360C847400223ECCB@entdc1ms02.corp.gomez.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

You could always extend `SmtpAppender` to implement the functionality you need.

Like this [example post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2410218/74585).