# Why sometimes Log4net events are logging with random event count, though buffer size is already configured?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, buffer, log4net

I've implemented BufferingAppenderSkeleton in my custom logger class and override SendBuffer method for logging batch logs in the database.

Here is an implementation:

```
protected override void SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();
        if (events != null && events.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var log in events)
            {
                var logWithLogSessionId = GetLogWithLogSession(log);
                logs.Add(logWithLogSessionId);
            }
        }     
        Analytics.SaveLogs(logs);
    }
```

And here web.config configuration for log4net:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="LogAppender" type="MyApp.LogAppender">
  <bufferSize value="20"/>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="LogAppender"/>
</root>
```

As per [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_BufferingAppenderSkeleton.htm), this method will trigger only when event count reaches equal to configured buffer size but sometimes this is calling with random event counts.

eg.
Sometimes triggers when there is only 1 event in the buffer, sometimes when event count reached buffer size + 1 etc?

Comment: Are you setting any other appender options within the class itself? Reading the  `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` source, the behavior is pretty consistent (output 21 events when the buffer is full). Unless you are using `Lossy` and/or `Evaluator` ?

Comment: nope, I set only the default option by calling ActivateOptions() method.

Comment: Have you tried not calling `ActivateOptions` ? Unless you are actually changing options in the adapter constructor I don't think you need/should call it... not sure if it makes any difference though...

Comment: As per documentation, ActivateOptions() should be called to initialize user-defined configurations like buffersize and other configurations for log4net. I don't think calling this method would create such problem though I went through the source code of BufferingAppenderSkeleton and found above behaviour is a functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferSize` property represents number of events that can be stored in memory, not number of event to be send in `SendBuffer` method. If you set `BufferSize` to 20, than 21st event will trigger that method and will be sent with other events as well. Check [SendFromBuffer](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/BufferingAppenderSkeleton.cs#L544) method in `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` class.

So basically, if you want to send 20 events in batch, set your `BufferSize` to 19.

This might seems wrong, but you will need to see how `Lossy` and `Evaluator` properties in `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` works. If you set `Lossy` to `true`, then you will only keep 20 latest/most important messages in memory, and disregards oldest events until `Evaluator` triggers `SendBuffer`. Check implementation of [Append](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/BufferingAppenderSkeleton.cs#L499) method to fully understand this.

Comment: Thanks @Peska for answering.